# If value appears on master sheet, insert corresponding data into second sheet.

Tags: excel, sorting, indexing

I have two worksheets that list the billing and client information and which employee managed that deal. The first sheet is the Master sheet that all of the deals go into. The second set of sheets belong to each individual employee to track their deals over the year. I need a formula that will allow me to input the deal and client data into the Master Sheet, and then will automatically copy that data into each individual employee's sheet if they participated in the deal.

The Master sheet looks like this:

**Client         Fee                   Employee** 

Client 1              $50                    Lauren 
Client 2             $60                    Alison 
Client 3             $40                    Lauren

I would then need the "Lauren" spreadsheet to automatically update like this:

**Client                 Fee**  

Client 1                $50 
Client 3                $40

and the "Alison" spreadsheet to automatically update like this:

**Client              Fee** 

Client 2             $60

I don't think index/match or VLOOKUP will work in this case, because there will be several different client names associated with each employee name, so there's not a unique value to match on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes:

1. The data on the master are in columns A, B, and C.
2. Row 1 on the master has the headers (Client, Fee, Employee) and the  data begin in row 2.
3. The master sheet is in fact called 'master'.

Now follow these steps:

1. Create a new sheet. You can name it anything (perhaps `Lauren`).
2. In cell A1 type `Lauren`.
3. In cell A3 type `Client`. In cell B3 type `Fee`.

Select the range `A4:B4` and in the Formula Bar paste this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(master!$A:$B,SMALL(IF(master!C$1:C$9999=$A$1,ROW(C$1:C$9999)),ROW(1:1)),{1,2}),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now with those two cells still selected, copy them. Then select a range below them (two columns wide and as deep as you like) and paste.

This worksheet is now Lauren's report.

4. Right-click the tab at the bottom of the sheet, and select `Move or Copy`.
5. Check `Create a copy`. Then select `(move to end)` from the list, and click OK.
6. Rename the new sheet anything (perhaps `Alison`).
7. In cell A1 type `Alison`.
8. Make a new sheet for each additional employee.

> The formula given above assumes the master sheet will never have more than 9999 records. If that is incorrect then edit the formula changing the 9999's to a larger number.